# Automatically renumber object key after item is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have an object that looks like this:

```
0

    Object { id="24105",  x="10",  y="4",  more...}
1

    Object { id="24104",  x="6",  y="5",  more...}
2

    Object { id="24103",  x="10",  y="6",  more...}
3

    Object { id="24102",  x="10",  y="3",  more...}
4

    Object { id="24101",  x="8",  y="6",  more...}
5

    Object { id="24100",  x="6",  y="1",  more...}
6

    Object { id="24099",  x="10",  y="8",  more...}
7

    Object { id="24098",  x="8",  y="3",  more...}
8

    Object { id="24097",  x="8",  y="7",  more...}
9

    Object { id="24096",  x="10",  y="2",  more...}
10

    Object { id="24095",  x="8",  y="1",  more...}
11

    Object { id="24094",  x="6",  y="2",  more...}
12

    Object { id="24093",  x="6",  y="8"}
13

    Object { id="24092",  x="8",  y="8",  more...}
14

    Object { id="24091",  x="6",  y="4",  more...}
15

    Object { id="24090",  x="6",  y="7",  more...}
16

    Object { id="24089",  x="10",  y="1",  more...}
17

    Object { id="24088",  x="4",  y="8",  more...}
18

    Object { id="24087",  x="8",  y="2",  more...}
19

    Object { id="24086",  x="6",  y="6",  more...}
20

    Object { id="24085",  x="10",  y="7",  more...}
21

    Object { id="24084",  x="6",  y="3",  more...}
22

    Object { id="24083",  x="8",  y="5",  more...}
23

    Object { id="24082",  x="10",  y="5",  more...}
24

    Object { id="24081",  x="4",  y="7",  more...}
```

As you can see, item 12 in the object contains less data than the others, and should be removed. I have used delete() to do that, but that doesn't renumber the other items, which causes later errors when I cycle through object in a for loop.

I've tried using splice(), but that causes an error because (as far as I can tell) my object is an object and not an array. I'm not entirely sure of the difference.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is this an array of objects?

Comment: This doesn't look like an object...?

Comment: use an array of objects rather than an object with numbers (that are actually strings) as keys.

Comment: The example "code" is confusing. Can you please show valid JS so we can better understand the issue?

Comment: Do you have to femove property with key 12, and after that set value from next key to 12 and so on? If so, look at ability to use an array instead of an object. But if you really need to use object you still can create helper function which handles such behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you got something like this, an object disguised as array:

```
{
    0: { id:"24097",  x:"8",  y:"7",},
    1: { id:"24096",  x:"10",  y:"2",},
    2: { id:"24095",  x:"8",  y:"1",}
}
```

Transform into a real array:

```
items = Object.keys( items ).map( function( index ){
    return items[index];
});
```

And use splice.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the no. of properties in the object using `Object.keys` and remove the one which has less than expected.

> Object.keys() returns an array whose elements are strings
>   corresponding to the enumerable properties found directly upon object.
>   The ordering of the properties is the same as that given by looping
>   over the properties of the object manually.

```
  Object.keys(obj).length
```

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/X6jzs/45/